# How to build XGBoost for multi-GPU on a Ubuntu 18.04 workstation

Tags: cmake, gpu, xgboost

### Can anyone describe in explicit detail the steps to building and installing XGBoost for multi-GPU?

*Below is a log of the non-trivial build process, the comments section contains the correct commands to download xgboost and submodules. I remain unclear on the install process, post build.*

My attempts to make this work have led me down a path of [installing NCCL2 from nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/nccl-install-guide/index.html#debian), upgrading cmake to version 3.16.4 (>3.12 is required), and attempting to [build XGBoost for GPU](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html).

Commands from the XGBoost documentation summarized below:

In the directory of the cloned [XGBoost library from Github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost),

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake … -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DUSE_NCCL=ON -DNCCL_ROOT=/path/to/nccl2
make -j4
```

Finally, if the 'make' command works, how do you install this build? The docs refer to installing with `python3 setup.py install` in the xgboost/python-package folder, but does this link to the build folder just created or the master build without multi-GPU support?

My workstation is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, CUDA 10.2, nvidia driver 440.44.

Comment: Does it use submodules? `git submodule update --init`

Comment: Does this directory exist `/home/ubuntu/Downloads/xgboost-master/dmlc-core`? It looks like you forgot the `--recursive` flag when doing a git clone

Comment: dmlc-core folder exists but is empty. I downloaded the library using the github button, instead of using git commands. How would I use git commands to pull the library and the submodules?

Comment: The documentation you linked is *explicit* about using `--recursive` when cloning this repo (see [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-xgboost-from-source)). As suggested, run the commands `git submodule update --init` from the `~/Downloads/xgboost-master` directory. Then, it's probably a good idea to delete your `build` directory and run the four commands mentioned in your question post again.

Comment: Second attempt was made with cmds: `git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost --recursive`, `cd xgboost`, `git checkout tags/v0.90`, and `git submodules update --init`. This installed the all submodules, then `make -j4` to build. How do I install this build?